# Removing glare with opencv and keeping edges removed from the glare

Tags: python, opencv

I have this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqcsE.jpg

And i am trying to get the contours of the image but as we can see in this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMktn.jpg
where there is glare, the contours of some circles are not  drawn.

I assume that if i get the glare off on this photo, when i use canny, the edges will be drawn correctly?

I am new to openCV, i've read some post on here and tried out some techniques, but it didn't work out at all.

Note: i am doing this in python
Anyone could help ? Thanks a lot.

**What i tried first :**

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('Photos/board.jpg')

canny = cv.Canny(img, 125, 175)

contours, hierarchies = cv.findContours(canny, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

blank = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype='uint8')
cv.drawContours(blank, contours, -1, (0,0,255),1)
cv.imshow('Contours drawn', blank)
```

**results** : https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSSFE.jpg

**Second attempt a bit better but useless things appears in the result**

```
adaptive_thresh = cv.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY, 13, 2)
cv.imshow('Adaptive thresholding', adaptive_thresh)

canny = cv.Canny(adaptive_thresh, 125, 175)
cv.imshow('Canny edges', canny)
```

**Results** (Theres so much white pixels that appear on the photo : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChZIc.jpg

Comment: Please post your code or a part of it. What are your cv2.threshold parameters before your cv2.findContours ?

Comment: @Panda50 added way more info, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to change the 2nd value of your Canny detection like this :

`canny = cv.Canny(img, 25, 175)`

the lower threshold (second argument) is set lower then you can avoid this glare effect. More info [here](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_canny/py_canny.html)

From my point of view, you can also work in hsv space which is more confomfortable if you want to extract informations from images with effects like this. More info about [hsv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). The Fig. 3 a) speaks for itself.

Here is the full code, you had some errors in yours (and maybe you use an old opencv release)

```
import numpy as np
img = cv.imread(r'C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\board.jpeg')
canny = cv.Canny(img, 25, 175)

img2, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(canny, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

blank = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype='uint8')
cv.drawContours(blank, contours, -1, (0,0,255),1)
cv.imshow('Contours drawn', blank)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

EDIT: I also want to tell you that it'll be difficult to use the extracted coordinates here. You'd better use [circle detection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d70/tutorial_hough_circle.html) and [line detection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html) to extract and use the coordinates of the board and pucks.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it definately works better with these settings, also since the puck color will need to be recognized do you recommend a certain tool ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: To get the color, you'll need to go into hsv (for sure). Then, if set of colors is always the same you can apply mask on it and see where you have your puck. Here is a good tutorial to teach you how to deal with colors : https://automaticaddison.com/how-to-apply-a-mask-to-an-image-using-opencv/

Comment: @Panda50 hello, do you please mind updating the first link to "more info" regarding Canny threshold values for avoiding glare? Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes opencv tutorials disapears. I've updated links.